# How to properly measure a 200 A/5 A CT using an Arduino?

Tags: power, resistors, arduino-uno, current-transformer

I've seen multiple projects for energy monitoring explaining how to calculate values using a Current Transformer (CT), however, all the CTs that were mentioned have high turn ratios.

The CT available to me is a 200 A/5 A CT. After plugging in their calculations I get a load resistor value of less than 0.6 Ω with a power rating that needs to be impossibly high.

Since the load resistor is impossible, what else can I do? How am I suppose to calculate the load resistor's size?

I have also tried using the [ACS712](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs712-datasheet.pdf) 5 A sensor to try to get the secondary of the CT, but no luck.

Comment: Put a link to your CT's datasheet.

Comment: Something like this https://docs.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/yhdc-sct-013-000-ct-sensor-report.html

Answer (score 0):

Current transformers with traditional "current outputs" typically have relatively low turn ratios, and output currents of 5A or 1A at full load. The high output currents mean thick wires to the meter, but good noise resistance.

They normally specify a maximum power dissipation in the ammeter's *shunt*, which for small cores is often just a couple of watts. This means very low resistance shunts in the meter, especially if they have 5A secondaries. The voltage developed over the shunt will therefore be similarly low. However that is not an issue as the electromechanical moving iron meters they were originally designed for work on current and typically only needed a fraction of a mA for FSD.

"Voltage output" current meters are designed with much higher turns ratios, and therefore much low current outputs.  This allows thin wires, but can lead to more concerns with noise.

They have the same power limits, but the low full load currents means they can be used with much larger *burden resistors*.  These are typically sized to give 3v3 at full load. Values in the 50R-200R range are common, and the resistors are often internal to the transformers.

High-turns ratios, voltage output CTs are great for ADC inputs, but can also be used with moving iron voltmeters (which are the same sensitive moving iron meters but with series resistors instead of shunts)

Using the formulae for calculating a *burden resistor*, with a target of 3V3 at full load, with a low turns ratio high current output transformer, will inevitably lead to excessive power dissipation.  For example, with your 5A secondary this would mean over 17W dissipation at full load.

Instead you need to calculate a shunt/burden resistance that is low enough to stay inside the power budget, and then work with the resulting low signal voltage.